# Solving initial value problem with Taylor Series expansion $dx/dt=x^2, x(0)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

I have series of homework questions that call for using Taylor series to solve initial value problems so can someone solve this example and explain what they are doing? I also want to know what elementary function the solution represents, radius of convergence, and the domain of $t$?

**Update:**

I have found that the Taylor series expansion can be represented as a geometric series, $\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty t^n$. I did the following $x(t)=\frac{x(0)}{0!}t^0+\frac {x'(0)}{1!}t^1+\frac {x''(0)}{2!}t^2...$, where $x'(t)=x(0)^2=1, x''(t)=d^2x(t)/dt^2=2x(t)(x(t))^2$, and substituted in the initial value $x(0)=1$.

So I can see that the radius of convergence is $(-1,1).$ What is the elementary function, what is that asking about?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? It is mandatory to give your own thoughts on questions here...

Answer (score 0):

Solving this ODE is pretty easy $\frac{dx}{x^2}=dt$ or $\frac{1}{x_0}-\frac{1}{x}=t$ Solving for $x$ and using the intial condition will answer you "What elementary function does the solution represent".

In order to solve this problem you need to write $x(t)$ as a taylor expantion:
$$x(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n$$

From your initial condition we know
$$ x(t=0)=1=a_0$$

Now differentiate this to get
$$x'(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nt^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}t^{n}$$

For the right side of the equation you have to calculate $x^2= (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n)^2$ using the Cauchy product formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) we get.

$$x^2= (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n)^2=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\sum_{l=0}^{n}a_la_{n-l})t^n$$

Now we plug the series expression for $x'(t)$ and $x^2$ into the differential equation $x'(t)=x^2$.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}t^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\sum_{l=0}^{n}a_la_{n-l})t^n$$

If you compare both sides of the equations for the coefficients of the powers of $t$, you will be able to recursivly calculate your $a_n$ values using

$$(n+1)a_{n+1}=\sum_{l=0}^{n}a_la_{n-l}$$

and

$$a_0=1$$

Try it out and come back if you have further questions.

Comment: This does not make much sense to me, I have tried a different approach in my edit, does it look right?

Comment: Your solution is not the general approach. Please look at my edited calculation. Maybe you can complete it with the new information.